# Switch to root ( using "sudo su -" ) before executing a command via Ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, sudo

TL; DR: Is there a way for me to make Ansible execute "sudo su -" ( not "sudo su - root") before executing the required command?

I have a remote server that I usually manage using Ansible. The problem is that I have a very strict list of command that I can execute using sudo.

Fortunately I can actually do "sudo su -" to get a root shell but I can't find a way for Ansible to do that.

From what I could understand, I can become root but Ansible issues a "sudo su - root" which doesn't suits me.

I've been messing with sudo and become parameters but couldn't find a solution which makes me think that it might not work, so the question is:

Is this feasible?

Comment: Of course it's feasible. Ansible is open source, after all.

Comment: that said, it doesn't look to me like the code is running `sudo su -` either, but that it's actually running something more like `sudo -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=randomjunkhere] password: ' -u root /bin/sh -c "actual command to run here"`.

Comment: ...and the random junk is changing every time, so you won't be able to whitelist it in the sudoers file either. Which makes the wrapper approach look even better.

Answer (score 1):

In `lib/ansible/utils/__init__.py`, see the `make_sudo_cmd` function, particularly the line:

```py
sudocmd = '%s -k && %s %s -S -p "%s" -u %s %s -c %s' % (
    C.DEFAULT_SUDO_EXE, C.DEFAULT_SUDO_EXE, C.DEFAULT_SUDO_FLAGS,
    prompt, sudo_user, executable or '$SHELL', pipes.quote('echo %s; %s' % (success_key, cmd)))
```

Now, one might hope that simply passing an empty string for `sudo_user` through your playbook might suffice; however, at some intervening layers, this is defaulted to `root` if its value is falsey (and an empty string, in Python, is indeed falsey). Thus, you'll need to make a more invasive modification to this code.

One option (which I'd seriously consider) is replacing `DEFAULT_SUDO_EXE` (in the constants module, here given as `C`) with a wrapper for the command you've generated yourself. Another is replacing `sudo_user` with, say, `(sudo_user if (sudo_user and sudo_user != 'root') else '')`.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
- hosts: application
  become: yes
  become_exe: "sudo su -"
  become_method: su
  tasks:
```